# Are residues from seasoning coating harmful when using carbon steel pan?

Tags: food-safety, seasoning, carbon-steel

I seasoned this carbon steel pan a few months ago, but after several times I cooked, the seasoning coating started to flake. I wonder are the residues harmful? Can I remain the way it is or should I scrub off all of them and re-season again? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Can you take a look at the answer to this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54642/how-to-maintain-a-smooth-seasoning-on-carbon-steel-skillets?rq=1 ... and see if it addresses your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain a smooth seasoning on carbon steel skillets?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54642/how-to-maintain-a-smooth-seasoning-on-carbon-steel-skillets)

Comment: What oil are you using for seasoning the pan?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wok patina comes off](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34420/wok-patina-comes-off)

Answer (score 1):

Just a note that if you use flax seed oil to season, it is notorious for flaking later. Also you may be seasoning with too much fat/oil when you heat it to create the polymerized surface.

The way to season carbon steel, woks, and cast iron is to wipe oil in the pan then wipe it out so that you can barely see a sheen of remaining oil. THEN heat it to the smoke point and let it fully dry and repeat, repeat, repeat! Again, when you first put in the oil/fat, you MUST wipe it out. That will allow for the polymerization to work as intended and not leave a surplus, sticky, or exessive quantity that doesn't complete polymerization with the pan in full.

Bon appetit!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the jury is still out on whether the black bits are harmful or not, but they will break off into whatever you cook now so....
The best way might be to start over again - to clean the pan
Simmer one quart of water in the pan on your stove. When the water is simmering, add 1 tbsp cream of tartar, 1 tbsp lemon juice and 1 tbsp white vinegar. Simmer for 15 minutes. Turn off the heat and allow the mixture to cool.
Then carry out the seasoning process again as per the following; 
Complete initial washing with soap and water to remove any residue from the above process. thanks
Preheat the wok over high heat. ...
Perform a water test by throwing a drop of water on the pan. ...
Add in about 2 tablespoons of oil and reduce heat to medium-high.
Add aromatics like chopped onions, ginger, and garlic to the pan. ...
Reduce heat to medium.